# azkaban h2.mv.db is too big and is that a problem?

Tags: h2, azkaban

we have used azkaban about 4 month and found that the h2.mv.db file is so big.
Is this a problem need to be solved?
How can we reduce the size of h2?
and is there any way to transform into mysql?
many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Azkaban exec server . Currently you are using Azkaban solo server which has internal h2 database . Azkaban exec server has an external mysql database.